# Teradata SIGNAL/RESIGNAL usage instead of RAISEERROR

Tags: signals, teradata

How can I implement **SIGNAL/RESIGNAL** instead of sql **RAISEERROR** in below scenario because I do not know what exactly should be the SQLSTATE for user defined condition:

```
begin
  if() 
    begin 
     ------
    end;
  else if()
    begin 
    --------
    end;
  else
    begin
     RAISEERROR('invalid request')
   end

end;
```

**EDITED CODE:**

```
SIGNAL SQLSTATE 'U0100' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'MY message';
```

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-signal-resignal/ try this one.

Comment: Actually i need this to be done in teradata... For this I implement the below code, is it correct? please see the edited code in question

Comment: yes . this should work. Is it giving any error?

Comment: yes finally it worked for me.

Comment: can you share the code snippet which worked for you